# How to append in Jquery html code with existing css still used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, append

I have this function in java script

```
function appendAllQna(qnaList, num){
    for (var i in qnaList){ 
        var qnaCom = "";
        qnaCom += "<div class='scomment scommentLine'>";
        if(qnaList[i].sellerYn == "Y"){
            qnaCom += "<div class='avatar defaultstore'>";
        }else{
            qnaCom += "<div class='avatar defaultuser'>";
        }
        qnaCom += "<img src=''></div><table class='subTab'>";
        qnaCom += "<tbody><tr><td class='infoME'>";     
        if(qnaList[i].sellerYn == "Y"){
            qnaCom += "<span class='name'>";
            qnaCom += qnaList[i].nickNm;
            qnaCom += "</span><span class='badge'></span>";
        }else{
            qnaCom += "<span class='name'>";
            qnaCom += qnaList[i].memNM;
            qnaCom += "</span>";
        }
        var page = document.getElementById("addMoreQna"+num);
        page.append(qnaCom);
    }
}
```

and this is the div I declare to be appended in my jsp

```
<div id="addMoreQna<%= i%>"></div>
```

I want to append so the html will appear also with the css existing in page. But the result is only the code appears like this:

```
<div class='scomment scommentLine'><div class='avatar defaultuser'><img src=''></div><table class='subTab'><tbody><tr><td class='infoME'><span class='name'>Putri</span><div class='scomment scommentLine'><div class='avatar defaultuser'><img src=''></div><table class='subTab'><tbody><tr><td class='infoME'><span class='name'>Putri</span><div class='scomment scommentLine'><div class='avatar defaultuser'><img src=''></div><table class='subTab'><tbody><tr><td class='infoME'><span class='name'>Putri</span><div class='scomment scommentLine'><div class='avatar defaultuser'><img src=''></div><table class='subTab'><tbody><tr><td class='infoME'><span class='name'>undefined</span>enter code here
```

Not the right apprearance. What should I do? Thanks in advance. Anyway I'm still beginner :D

Comment: Could you explain more what your question is, do you want to know how to append a div with an class or id?
or do you want to move a div or??

Comment: I want to show html view, but in fact it's appearing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append is a jquery method but you are using it as if it were a javascript method.

to use the jquery method use:

```
$('#addMoreQna' + num).append(qnaCom);
```

or if pure js:

```
page.innerHTML += qnaCom;
```

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.